# OnDraw() Method not getting Called

Tags: android, view, ondraw

```
// DrawTargetMarker.java

    public class DrawTargetMarker extends View {
    //Class type variables
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private static final String TAG = DrawTargetMarker.class.getSimpleName();
    private int mX, mY;
    private int mRadius = 10;

    //Constructor
    public DrawTargetMarker(Context context, int curX, int curY){
        super(context);
        this.mX = curX;
        this.mY = curY;
        // Forces the canvas to draw the object
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Creating paint instance
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // Setting the paint's style 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        // Setting the width of the stroke
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        // Setting the color of the object to be drawn
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Draw the circle using the specified paint
        canvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, mRadius, paint);  
    }
}

// RecordShots.java

...
...
....


recordShots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recordCount.setText(String.valueOf(count++));
            Log.i(TAG, "Points Recorded ( " + ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_x() + "," + ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_y() + ")");
            mDrawTargetMarker = new DrawTargetMarker(getApplicationContext(), ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_x(), ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_y());

// points recorded will be showing two values like (120,20), depending upon the object 
// position in the view.            


        }

    });
```

So , My query is when I click on the button, is shows me the exact position of the object in the view in the form of (x,y) but I tried to pass that x,y along with the context to the view, so at that x,y I need to place a object and repeat the process until I end.

So the Control is moving to the view, but the problem is that the OnDraw() method  fails to be called, that is responsible for drawing the object in that specified x,y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you need to attach `DrawTargetMarker` to the activity's main view (See [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29)). And when you launch the Activity using an intent, the View's onDraw() method should be called directly. You should not be calling the `DrawTargetMarker` constructor directly.

Comment: Hi Rajath, Thanks for your reply , i tried that why too, but i am not getting the solution.

Comment: Is your `DrawTargetMarker` view attached to an Activity? If so, is the activity running?

Comment: I have already linked the view with the activity through mDrawTargetMarkermDrawTargetMarker = new DrawTargetMarker(getApplicationContext(), ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_x(), ((TargetTrackerGlobalVariable) getApplicationContext()).getCurrent_y());

Comment: So using the trace(Debug/Breakpoints) i checked .The control moves upto the view's( DrawTargetMarker) constructor upto invalidate(), but not moving to the onDraw().....